# Is .findIndex() a Higher Order Function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

Basically I understand that `.filter()`, `.reduce()`, and `.map()` are higher-order functions because they take other functions as their arguments, like this:

`arrayOfWords.filter(words => words.length > 6);`

`unflattenedArray.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue);`

`arrayOfIntegers.map(x => x * 2);`

So then is `.findIndex()` also a higher-order function?

Seems to operate just like the others:

```
let fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cantaloupe", "blueberries", "grapefruit"];

let index = fruits.findIndex(fruit => fruit === "blueberries");
```

Comment: Just curious. Your definition of a higher order function is accurate. So what created a doubt whether `findIndex` is one or not?

Comment: Trying to learn about higher-order functions via Eloquent JavaScript https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html and the author seems to emphasize `filter`, `map`, and `reduce`, and while `findIndex` is mentioned, it doesn't seems like it's given as much attention. Also other tutorials (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LFjnY1PEDA) seem to only talk about `map`, `sort`, `reduce`, `filter`, and `fill` when it comes to higher-order functions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, `findIndex` is a higher-order function.

The `findIndex()` method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise, it returns -1, indicating no element passed the test.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: Thank you. So then essentially any function that needs to take another function as it's argument is considered a higher-order function?

Comment: yes, almost defined about higher order function is a function that takes a function as an argument, or returns a function https://medium.com/javascript-scene/higher-order-functions-composing-software-5365cf2cbe99