# JavaScript Logic's: Convert events array to a comma separated string and add it into a single variable

Tags: javascript, foreach

Good Morning,

I have a little logic's question I cant quiet wrap my head around. I have an array of values I get from a forEach which returns an array like this.

```
"events": [["IDLING:END"],["TOWING:END"]],
```

I need to add this to a single variable separated by n comma. This events type can have multiple entries for example, it could also have an extra SPEED:END entry etc. So I need it to be like...

```
let eventResult = 'IDLING:END,TOWING:END,SPEED:END'
```

So now my question: How do I add these and then check if there is any extra entries and add all of the new entries only once. I have multiple gps positions with the exact same data and I need to add every entry only once, but as I said this can potentially have more entries at any given moment, or should I say extra values.

I hope my explanation is clear.
Warm Regards

Comment: To understand the problem
1. You want to convert `"events": [["IDLING:END"],["TOWING:END"]],` to `'IDLING:END,TOWING:END,SPEED:END'`
2. You do not want to have repeated entry for any event. 

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: When you add all your entries, to convert from `Array` to `'IDLING:END,TOWING:ENG,SPEED:END'` . You can use the Join method. `Array.join(",")`. Do you need this?

Comment: Yes. I need to join them. I just need some logics to first add the entries that at present I can see when I console log(position.events) I need to add each entry once and then check if there is any other entries that I might not know of. This can be any value depending on the unit that sends it. And the same array value comes through mulitple times. 267 times to be exact at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have done it in the following way. I also agree that there are various ways to remove duplicates.

```js
let events = [["a:a"], ["b:b"], ["a:a"]];
let arrToJoin = [];

const flatArray = events.flat();

flatArray.forEach((e) => {
  if (arrToJoin.findIndex((a) => a === e) === -1) {
    arrToJoin.push(e);
  }
});

console.log(arrToJoin.join(","));
```

Comment: Looks interesting. Thank you. Going to try it out :)

Comment: That actually works nice. Care to explain what exactly this does. Especially the (a) => a === e) === -1) part?

Comment: What I accidentally stumbled on was just doing this
if (position.events.length !== 0) {
      eventResult = position.events.join()
    } else {
      eventResult = 'N/A'
    }
But I am not sure I am doing the right checks.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55913179/is-findindex-a-higher-order-function-in-javascript